# Variance interval charting in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

How do I create an annual MODIS NDVI time series chart by day-of-year (DOY) that shows the interquartile range as an interval envelope with the current year's observations overlayed?

I want to put this year's observations in the context of the expected range - something similar to ggplot2's [`geom_ribbon()` function](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_ribbon.html#examples):

[image]

I've not seen an example for how to make an interval envelope chart with Earth Engine. The closest example I have seen is to simply plot the time series of all years as separate lines using the `doySeriesByYear()` function.

```js
// Define area of interest and display on map.
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-122.10333508394413, 36.980921854180906],
          [-122.10333508394413, 36.962269988961935],
          [-122.06179303072147, 36.962269988961935],
          [-122.06179303072147, 36.980921854180906]]], null, false);

Map.centerObject(aoi, 13);
Map.addLayer(aoi, {color: 'white'}, 'AOI');
Map.setOptions('SATELLITE');

// Load MODIS vegetation index data and subset a decade of NDVI images.
var band = 'NDVI';
var ndviCol = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2010-01-01', '2020-07-01'))
                  .select(band);

// Plot NDVI as an annual time series, year over year; emphasize 2020 with a
// thicker, darker line.
print(ui.Chart.image
          .doySeriesByYear({
            imageCollection: ndviCol,
            bandName: band,
            region: aoi,
            regionReducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
            scale: 500,
            sameDayReducer: ee.Reducer.mean()
          })
          .setOptions({
            hAxis: {
              title: 'Day of year',
              titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
            },
            vAxis: {
              title: 'NDVI (x1e4)',
              titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true},
              viewWindow: {min: 4000, max: 8000},
              baseline: 0
            },
            lineWidth: 0.5,
            colors: ['#4caf50'],
            series: {10: {lineWidth: 5, color: '#087f23'}},
            legend: {position: 'none'},
          }));
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Charts can render [interval charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/intervals); to take advantage of it in Earth Engine, you need to construct a custom data table and provide it as input to the generic `ui.Chart` function and set `interval` chart options. I've added an example of an area (envelope) interval and box interval to the question code:

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c06011ed8190b000bec8c2b504be8118)

```js
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */


// Define area of interest and display on map.
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-122.10333508394413, 36.980921854180906],
          [-122.10333508394413, 36.962269988961935],
          [-122.06179303072147, 36.962269988961935],
          [-122.06179303072147, 36.980921854180906]]], null, false);

Map.centerObject(aoi, 13);
Map.addLayer(aoi, {color: 'white'}, 'AOI');
Map.setOptions('SATELLITE');

// Load MODIS vegetation index data and subset a decade of NDVI images.
var band = 'NDVI';
var ndviCol = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2010-01-01', '2020-07-01'))
                  .select(band);

// Plot NDVI as an annual time series, year over year; emphasize 2020 with a
// thicker, darker line.
print(ui.Chart.image
          .doySeriesByYear({
            imageCollection: ndviCol,
            bandName: band,
            region: aoi,
            regionReducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
            scale: 500,
            sameDayReducer: ee.Reducer.mean()
          })
          .setOptions({
            hAxis: {
              title: 'Day of year',
              titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
            },
            vAxis: {
              title: 'NDVI (x1e4)',
              titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true},
              viewWindow: {min: 4000, max: 8000},
              baseline: 0
            },
            lineWidth: 0.5,
            colors: ['#4caf50'],
            series: {10: {lineWidth: 5, color: '#087f23'}},
            legend: {position: 'none'},
          }));


// Plot current year NDVI in the context of interannual variance.
// To do this, build two feature collections: one to hold median and
// interquartile range (IQR), and one to hold current year observations, then
// construct a data table from values of the two feature collections.

// Add a day of year (DOY) property to each NDVI image.
ndviCol = ndviCol.map(function(img) {
  return img.set('doy', img.date().getRelative('day', 'year'));
});

// Define a distinct DOY collection for joining all matching images by DOY.
var distinctDoy = ndviCol.filterDate('2010-01-01', '2011-01-01');

// Perform a join between the distinct DOY collection and the entire collection.
// Include DOY matches in a property called 'doy_matches_iqr'.
var joinByDoy = ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'doy', rightField: 'doy'});
var doyMatchesIqr = ee.ImageCollection(
    ee.Join.saveAll('doy_matches_iqr').apply(distinctDoy, ndviCol, joinByDoy));

// Calculate the interquartile range and median among interannual, same-day
// observations.
var iqrIc = ee.ImageCollection(doyMatchesIqr.map(function(img) {
  var doyCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(img.get('doy_matches_iqr'));
  return doyCol
      .reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([25, 50, 75], ['p25', 'p50', 'p75']))
      .set({'doy': img.get('doy')});
}));

// Reduce the IQR image bands by a region of interest and return the results
// as properties of a feature collection.
var iqrFc = iqrIc.map(function(img) {
  var stats = ee.Dictionary(img.reduceRegion(
      {reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: aoi, scale: 500}));

  return ee.Feature(null, {
    doy: img.get('doy'),
    p25: stats.get(band + '_p25'),
    p50: stats.get(band + '_p50'),
    p75: stats.get(band + '_p75'),
  });
});

// The IQR feature collection is complete, now work on the current year
// feature collection. The current year does not have a complete set of
// observations, missing observations need to be set to null. To do this,
// composite masked images representing all observations with the existing
// current year observations. First, make a copy of the distinct year collection
// where each image is completely masked out.
var distinctDoyMasked = distinctDoy.map(function(img) {
  return img.multiply(0).selfMask().set('doy', img.get('doy'));
});

// Filter the entire NDVI collection to the current year.
var currentYear =
    ndviCol
        .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01')
        // Merge the current year with the masked distinct DOY collection to
        // ensure the full set of annual observations (DOY) are represented
        // within the collection.
        .merge(distinctDoyMasked);

// Perform a join between the masked distinct DOY collection and the current
// year collection. Include DOY matches in a property called
// 'doy_matches_current'.
var doyMatchesCurrent =
    ee.ImageCollection(ee.Join.saveAll('doy_matches_current')
                           .apply(distinctDoyMasked, currentYear, joinByDoy));

// Create a mosiac by DOY, DOYs not yet observed in current year will be
// represented by masked (null) values.
var currentIc = ee.ImageCollection(doyMatchesCurrent.map(function(img) {
                    var doyCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
                        img.get('doy_matches_current'));
                    return doyCol.reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull()).set({
                      'doy': img.get('doy')
                    });
                  }))
                    .sort('doy');

// Reduce the current year NDVI images by a region of interest and return the
// results as properties of a feature collection.
var currentFc =
    currentIc
        .map(function(img) {
          var stats = ee.Dictionary(img.reduceRegion(
              {reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: aoi, scale: 500}));

          return ee.Feature(
              null, {doy: img.get('doy'), current: stats.get(band + '_first')});
        })
        .sort('doy');

// Combine the current year and IQR data per DOY into a new feature collection.
var tableRowsFc = currentFc.map(function(feature) {
  var doy = feature.get('doy');
  var thisIqr = iqrFc.filter(ee.Filter.eq('doy', doy)).first();
  var tableRow = [
    doy, feature.get('current'), thisIqr.get('p50'), thisIqr.get('p25'),
    thisIqr.get('p75')
  ];

  return ee.Feature(null, {table_row: tableRow});
});

// Convert the combined feature collection to a list of lists.
var dataTable = tableRowsFc.aggregate_array('table_row');

// Define a row of column names to prepend to the data table.
var colNames = ee.List([[
  {label: 'Day of year'}, {label: '2020'}, {label: 'Median and IQR'},
  {id: 'p25', role: 'interval'}, {id: 'p75', role: 'interval'}
]]);

// Prepend the column names to the data table.
dataTable = colNames.cat(dataTable);

// Get the data table client-side and use it to create variance charts.
dataTable.evaluate(function(dataTable) {
  // Create and display a variance envelope chart.
  var envelopeChart =
      ui.Chart({dataTable: dataTable, chartType: 'LineChart'}).setOptions({
        intervals: {'style': 'area'},
        hAxis:
            {title: 'Day of year', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
        vAxis:
            {title: 'NDVI (x1e4)', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
        series: {
          0: {color: '#087f23', lineWidth: 5},
          1: {color: '#4caf50', lineWidth: 0.5}
        }
      });
  print(envelopeChart);

  // Create and display a variance box chart.
  var boxChart =
      ui.Chart({dataTable: dataTable, chartType: 'LineChart'}).setOptions({
        intervals: {barWidth: 1, boxWidth: 1, lineWidth: 0, style: 'boxes'},
        hAxis:
            {title: 'Day of year', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
        vAxis:
            {title: 'NDVI (x1e4)', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
        series: {
          0: {color: '#087f23', lineWidth: 5},
          1: {color: '#4caf50', lineWidth: 0.5}
        }
      });
  print(boxChart);
});
```

[image]